# How to add tkinter in python without using conda environment h

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

I want to add tkinter in python.
I am just a starter programmer and I don't know much about python.
What should I do to install tkinter in python?

Help me out

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**First,** select a conda environment

**Second,** create a new terminal(Ctrl+Shift+`)

**Third,** take command `conda install tkinter`

**Fourth,** import tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is a standard python module, so you don't have to install anything to use it, just import it as you do with every other module:
`import tkinter` if you use python 3.x else `import Tkinter` for python 2.x

It doesn't need any special requirement, so just execute the .py file as you whould do with every other python script. Just remember that the tkinter window need the `root.mainloop()` to be kept open.

A simple example of a tkinter script for python 3:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()                # The main window declaration.
root.title("Hi!")             # The title of our window.

our_label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!")    # A label with a small message.
our_label.pack()           # Put it inside the window.

# This command is a loop that make your main window (the one made with tk.Tk())
# remain open, remember that this need to be the last line of code becuse  
# it's an infinite loop and code below it will never be executed.
root.mainloop()
```

*Et voilà!* That's a simple window with a label.
Run the .py file in the terminal as you do for all the python scripts with the command:

`python <file_name>.py`

and your window will appear.

For more info about tkinter widgets and how they work take a look at the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html).